# how to reduce memory usage drastically while combining numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, memory

i have 19 feature vectors and i want to combine them to all possible combinations of feature matrices. This leads me to 524288 different combinations (some contain only one feature vector,  one of them contains all 19). I constructed a dictionary `result`, that contains 524288 key value pairs like so `(feature1,feature2): [feature_vector1], [feature_vecttor2]`. Now I want to combine these feature vectors to form 524288 feature matrices.
this is how i tried to do that:

```
feature_names_and_values_tup_list = []
for key, val in result.items():
    #only one feature
    if len(key) == 1:
        feature_name = ''.join(key)
        feature_value = val
        feature_names_and_values_tup_list.append((feature_name, feature_value))
    #two features to combine
    elif len(key) == 2:
        feature_name = '_'.join(key)
        feature_value = numpy.append(val[0], val[1],1)
        feature_names_and_values_tup_list.append((feature_name, feature_value))
    #more than two features to combine
    elif len(key) > 2:
        feature_value = numpy.concatenate(val, axis=1)
        how_many +=1
        print(how_many)
        feature_names_and_values_tup_list.append((feature_na
```

This code exits after it did combine 33466 combinations with error message `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`. when i look up the memory usage in my system, i see that this part of the scripts results in over 114GB (!) memory usage.

I never had a problemlike this and dont know at all how to proceed. Do I need to have it run on a server? can i optimize my code? please give me some advice, im desperate and clueless.
Thank you in advance

Comment: The question I would ask is, why are you looking to get a matrix of all possible combinations?

Comment: because i want to find the ideal combination

Comment: and im not looing for one matrix with all possible combinations but multible matrices representing all combinations

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the right approach (as you experienced). What do you mean by "ideal", are you feeding your feature combination vectors to some kind of model?

Comment: Do you need to hold all the combinations in memory all at once?

Comment: @Ivan, yes, Im performing text classififcation and am searching for the set of features that yields the best results

Comment: @np8, no i dont think so but im not sure

Comment: Why not evaluate the results with batches of combinations, *versus* the entire dataset?

Comment: @Ivan if i understand you correctly I did try that. i tried to take only subsets of 'result' but it still happens

Comment: That's probably because you are concatenating your features. Could you elaborate on how these features are encoded (and their shapes)? How do you plan on combining `n` features together? Are you not retaining the same shape after combining multiple features?

Comment: some example shapes are (97, 614), (97, 300), (97, 1140). I combine them over axis 1 and the last elif code block shows how i concat n features

Comment: And how do you plan on "performing text classififcation", your input size doesn't seem fixed at all?

Comment: i dont understand? it worked when i tried

Comment: Could you show your model? I'm not sure I'm following: you are using a text classification model with inputs of varying size (I'm not talking about the *sequence length*), is that right?

Comment: the model doesnt realy matter here, sure i can show it but it has nothing to do with the question asked since it would be the next step.

Comment: when i trained and tested my models (logistic regression and naive bayes), i combines the features "by hand", i just picked some, appended them together and used this to train the model, one by one. so i only had one feature matrix per model, hence no difference in sizes

Comment: I do believe it has its importance, this might be a xy problem. I would recommend you edit your question with the full context.

Comment: A minor point that doesn't affect memory use.  `numpy.append(val[0], val[1],1)` is just `np.concatenate([val[0], val[1]], 1)`.  `np.append` is just a front end to `concatenate`.